# Incapable of catching error in if clause (updated with answer)

Tags: php

In this code below, $alb->error has an error message in it. I can verify this with echo, no problem.

The issue arises when I want to catch that error in an if clause. First, the code:

```
    if($action == "add")
    {
        //PUT CODE TO SAVE A NEW ALBUM HERE
        //SHOULD RETURN ALBUM ID
        $alb = new album();
        //fill object album with properties to be saved
        $alb->date = checkNull($_POST['alb_date']);
        $alb->name = checkNull($_POST['alb_name']);
        $alb->desc = checkNull($_POST['alb_desc']);
        $alb->cat_id = $_POST['categories'];
        //call save method of album
        $alb->create_album();

        //catch error
        if($alb->error <> "")
        {
            header("Location: add_album.php?error='$alb->error'");
        }

        //set album id to pass it along to add_pictures
        $alb_id = $alb->id;
    }
    elseif($action == "edit")
    {
        //PUT CODE TO SAVE EDITED ALBUM HERE
        //SHOULD RETURN ALBUM ID
    }

        header("Location: add_pictures.html?alb_id='$alb_id'");
```

After $alb->create_album(), $alb's error property is filled by omitting a required field in the input form. This is what I want. But then, I need to catch that error, and redirect the user to the previous page, where the error will be displayed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    //catch error
    if(isset($alb->error))
    {
        header("Location: add_album.php?error='$alb->error'");
    }
```

Didn't work.

```
    //catch error
    if(!is_null($alb->error))
    {
    header("Location: add_album.php?error='$alb->error'");
    }
```

No cigar.

```
    //catch error
    if($alb->error <> "")
    {
        header("Location: add_album.php?error='$alb->error'");
    }
```

still, zero joy.

The if clause never gets processed. What am I missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: All of those should work. Are you sure the `if` is being executed at all?

Comment: it isn't, that's the issue. If I echo $alb->error - I get my sql error about the contstraints on the table. So the property gets filled. But the if clause never gets fired

Comment: Then the problem is with where you've put the `if`, because it's never getting there.

Comment: I've edited my initial code block, to show you I'm calling the if clause right after creating the album.

Comment: if I replace the if statement with an echo of $alb->error, my error is printed on the screen...

Comment: What happens if you change `header(...)` to `echo $alb->error`?

Comment: @Barmar I just tried it now, and it's not getting fired still

Comment: Will `if ( $alb->error ) echo $alb->error;` fire?

Comment: But if you put an echo before and after the `if`, they both get executed?

Comment: @NathanDawson I just asked that.

Comment: putting an echo both before, and after made the if fire

Comment: How about: if ( $alb->error != null && $alb->error != "" && $alb->error != 0 && $alb->error != false )

Comment: about to update my post to show what was wrong. Thanks guys, I think I got it :)

Comment: Perhaps, you are emitting some output before the header.  Check to see if you have debugs turned on.

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question above. Post it as an answer below, then come back after the waiting period and mark it as accepted.

Comment: oops, ok - sorry about that. Will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I had a header redirect after my outer if clause for the type of action: if action=add or edit. When I wrapped it in an else clause, it worked:

```
    }
    elseif($action == "edit")
    {
        //PUT CODE TO SAVE EDITED ALBUM HERE
        //SHOULD RETURN ALBUM ID
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: add_pictures.html?alb_id='$alb_id'");
    }
```

Thanks for your help!!